# Matplotlib: Display numpy "sparse" array - Enlarge dots?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I can display numpy array easily like this:

```
plt.imshow(ary);
```

the problem is that the array is very sparse and I have to zoom 1-2 times to see "artefacts" or any structure.
What will you recommend so that I make this more visible.
How would you manipulate the array? May be some trick to enlarge the dots! set nearby pixels in some way?

=================================

here is my first attempt:

```
lst2 = np.where(ary > 0)
px = zip(lst2[0],lst2[1])
for x,y in px : ary[x-1:x+1, y-1:y+1] = ary[x,y]
```

---

My second question: would it be possible, If the values in the array are scaled to say range 0-1 or 0-255 or 0-100, to plot them with different colors or alphas in a single command?
I can not do:

```
plt.plot(x,y, '.', markersize=7, color='blue', alpha=ary[x,y] )
```

because x and y are arrays themselves and alpha/color accept single value only.
Is there one line solution or I have to do a loop.

Comment: What is the typical array shape and number of non-zero points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
y, x = np.nonzero(ary)
plt.plot(x, y, '.', markersize=5)
```